# How do I choose between ems and viewport sizes in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css

I started studying Web Development this summer and found myself in a bit of a pickle when I was reading about font sizes in HTML/CSS and their different units. 
Now after reading what W3schools had, I understood that if we want to content to be responsive then we use Viewport units (vw/vh etc) and when want browser-scalable content we use ems or percentages. (right?)

Now my question is what if we want flexibility for both Responsive sizes and scalability at the same time ? How do we get the benefits of both units?
(Can you please explain in laymen terms ^_^)

*I've already studied about different CSS units and their uses. Searched Stackoverflow and did google searches in general.*

```
<h1 style="font-size:10vw;">Responsive Text</h1>

<h1 style="font-size:10ems;">Scableable Text</h1>
```

Is there a way to use both the attributes of ems and viewport units?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can use the `calc()` function in CSS to make use of both if you wanted to. Some good examples here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/

Comment: Hey that's useful ^_^ Thank you so much. How ever isn't there a simpler way ?

Comment: Depends on what you're actually trying to do.